# Android Java compile error: Syntax error on "=",; expected

Tags: android, syntax, onclick, findviewbyid

I am getting the following error while trying to compile my java code in Eclipse:

"Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:MyHelloWorld [line:25]
   on TextButtonClicked(View)
 - Syntax error on token "=", ; expected"

```
package com.example.helloworldandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MyHelloWorld extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_hello_world);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my_hello_world, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void onTextButtonClicked(View view){
        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.haikuTextView);
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try doing a clean build from Project -> Clean

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public void onTextButtonClicked(View view){
        txtView = new TextView(this);
        txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.haikuTextView);
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: This will create a second `TextView` then try to overwrite it with a new reference. This won't work.